# Boolean function that checks whether a $4$-bit two's complement binary number is $\le-6$?

Tags: propositional-calculus

I am trying to figure out how I can turn this question into a Boolean function (which will then be turned into a boolean circuit).
I know that $-6$ in $4$-bit two's complement is 1010 and I know the two's complements that are less than $-6,$ but I have no idea how I would go about writing this as a function as I've only worked with boolean formulas such as: ¬A→(¬B∧¬C) etc

Comment: 4 bits is small enough that a good place to start might be to just write out which things should evaluate to true, and which things to false.

Answer (score 2):

$-6$ is $1010$, $-7$ is $1001$, $-8$ is $1000$; all others are bad for our purposes, so we have, with the bits labeled $abcd$,

$$\begin{align}
&ab'cd' + ab'c'd + ab'c'd'\\
=\,&ab'cd' + ab'c'd + ab'c'd' + ab'c'd'\\
=\,&ab'cd' + ab'c'd' + ab'c'd + ab'c'd'\\
=\,&ab'd'(c+c') + ab'c'(d+d')\\
=\,&ab'd'+ab'c'\\
=\,&ab'(c'+d')\\
=\,&ab'(cd)'
\end{align}$$

and any of those last three I'd call simplified.